# Safari search bar highlighting text in red

Tags: safari, highlight

This has been happening since a couple of days now but whenever I type something in Safari’s search bar at the top it highlights a certain section of the text in red. This is only happening in Safari on my iPad (9th Generation), not on MacBook.

I don’t know why this is happening all of a sudden or how to stop it. Any help would be appreciated! Screenshot for reference :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXiQL.jpg)